# How to write multiple csv file in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have file .csv file, I read all files together using `tidyverse` library. Now if I want to write the file then all file merged in to one file. How Can I write files separately?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-
  list.files(path = "D:/Data file", pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
  map_df(~read_csv(.))
library(zoo)

df$PAHs <- na.approx(df[,3])
```

that the data after I multiple uploads, did interpolation then write it
on the other hand the files did not comes as serial maintained, like
After A1, A10, A9, A2 like this

```
structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
63L, 24567L, 24568L, 24569L, 24570L, 24571L, 24572L, 24573L), 
    Station = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "B9", "B9", "B9", "B9", "B9", 
    "B9", "B9"), Depth.m. = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
    23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
    35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
    47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
    59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 1494L, 1495L, 1496L, 1497L, 
    1498L, 1499L, 1500L), PAHs = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
    25, 24.93333333, 24.86666667, 24.8, 24.73333333, 24.66666667, 
    24.6, 24.53333333, 24.46666667, 24.4, 24.33333333, 24.26666667, 
    24.2, 24.13333333, 24.06666667, 24, 23.88, 23.76, 23.64, 
    23.52, 23.4, 23.28, 23.16, 23.04, 22.92, 22.8, 22.68, 22.56, 
    22.44, 22.32, 22.2, 22.08, 21.96, 21.84, 21.72, 21.6, 21.48, 
    21.36, 21.24, 21.12, 21, 20.93333333, 20.86666667, 20.8, 
    20.73333333, 20.66666667, 20.6, 20.53333333, 20.46666667, 
    20.4, 20.33333333, 20.26666667, 20.2, 20.13333333, 20.06666667, 
    20, 5.3804, 5.367, 5.3536, 5.3402, 5.3268, 5.3134, 5.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-70L))
```

There are more data like A1, A2, A3, A4,....., B1, B2,.....C1...
but for word limitation I am showing A1 & B9

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` you could split your dataframe by `Station`. Then use e.g. `purrr::walk` to loop over the list of splitted df to save them separately:

```r
library(purrr)

tmp <- tempdir()

df_list <- split(df, df$Station)
purrr::iwalk(df_list, ~ write.csv(.x, file.path(tmp, paste0(.y, ".csv"))))

list.files(tmp, "\\.csv")
#> [1] "A1.csv" "B9.csv"
```

Comment: thanks but how can I do in the respected path? I did tmp <- dir("D:/Data file").  but after i did purr:: code it is showing error.

Comment: Try `tmp <- "D:/Data file"`.

Answer (score 0):

Read them in in the right order in the first place by sorting the names using `gtools::mixedsort` .  Also note that `list.files` takes a regex, not the glob shown in the question, and `Sys.glob` would be more appropriate here.  Also `read_csv` can take a vector of paths.

```
library(gtools)
library(magrittr)
library(readr)

"D:/Data file/*.csv" %>%
  Sys.glob %>%
  mixedsort %>%
  read_csv
```